# Openpgp Encrypt with Multiple Keys

Tags: encryption, pgp, openpgp.js

I'm trying to encrypt string with multiple keys but I get that error;
TypeError: Error encrypting message: key.getPrimaryUser is not a function

```
let pubKey = ['-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\r\nVersion: Keybase OpenPGP v1.0.0\r\nComment: https:\/\/keybase.io\/crypto\r\n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\r\ntnaYILB4TGqQCQ+VQMK8eKtkFZPDcS3nAgiKxj8tyk0=\r\n=Eocd\r\n-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----', '-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\r\nVersion: Keybase OpenPGP v1.0.0\r\nComment: https:\/\/keybase.io\/crypto\r\n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\r\nIEvOTSu34SI68FufqQTDKiWQWo1mBej98qsSoE7SAhcx\r\n=owPm\r\n-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----'];
let message = "Hello World";

function encryptData(pubkeys, plainText){
    let result;
    let sync = true;
    const encryptDecryptFunction = async() => {
        console.log('working');
        pubkeys = pubkeys.map(async (key) => {
            return (await openpgp.key.readArmored(key)).keys[0]
        });
        const options = {
            message: openpgp.message.fromText(plainText),       // input as Message object
            publicKeys: pubkeys, // for encryption                          // for signing (optional)
        }

        openpgp.encrypt(options).then(ciphertext => {
            result = ciphertext.data // '-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE ... END PGP MESSAGE-----'   
            sync = false;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    encryptDecryptFunction();
    while(sync){require('deasync').sleep(100);}
    return result;

}

encryptData(pubKey, message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue and it happens because in the part where you load the variable pubkeys :

```
  pubkeys = pubkeys.map(async (key) => {
      return (await openpgp.key.readArmored(key)).keys[0]
    })
```

needs to be changed to promises like this:

```
let publicKeysPromises = pubkeys.map(async (key) => {
      return (await openpgp.key.readArmored(key)).keys[0]
    });
```

Since it is an async operation and using the 'pubkeys' in your case in 'options' variable before it is fully resolved causes the issue. This happens because openPGP makes internal call to a function called getPrimaryUser when the function 'encrypt' is called with the 'options' {openpgp.encrypt(options)}. And when the public keys are read with readArmored it creates an Key object which in turn has 'getPrimaryUser' attached to it as an async function. Therefore the above promises need to be resolved before you can call the 'encrypt' function.

Therefore, next, you need to change the options to  the code below :

```
 const options = {
    message: openpgp.message.fromText(message),
    // resolve all promises returned before
    publicKeys: await Promise.all(publicKeysPromises),       // for encryption
    privateKeys: [privKeyObj]                         // for signing (optional)
    }
```

I hope this answers the question.